# Ask for user input using a SpriteFont on the screen present

Tags: c#, xna

For instance, consider a brick breaker game where once the ball falls below the paddle, the user would get a displayed message (using `SpriteFont`) asking whether he would like to play again. If that condition was met,and the sprite font stated 'Play again, enter 'y' for yes, 'n' for no' how would one proceed to take that input in XNA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you're gonna want to have a boolean to see if the game has ended or not. If you didn't have the boolean then the user could press Y or N anytime and the game would restart.

It should be simple to setup one anyways, just have it detect when the ball falls below the paddle and set the bool to true;

Then, the rest should be quite simple to figure out.

```
if (gameRestart)
        {
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Y))
            {
                // code for restart goes here
            }
            else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.N))
            {
                // do nothing, I guess?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on detecting key presses in XNA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx